# MySQL - SQL not searching for UTF 2019 (&#x2019;) single quote

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I have the following character in one of my row entry in a MySQL database:-

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

When I run the following sql query in phpmyadmin it says that no results are found.

SQL:-

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%ABC, D’EF%'
```

I've copy pasted the `title` from phpmyadmin as:-

```
ABC, DE'F
```

It's basically a WordPress project, the actual code is:-

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "' AND post_type = 'post'" );
```

Comment: The `’` character isn't the same as `'` - looks like you have one in the title and another in the query.

Comment: @JoelHinz That is correct. This is the point I want to explain. What can I do to make `’` searchable in MySQL.

Comment: It is searchable, though - all characters are. I mean, I don't doubt you that there's something wrong - but it isn't that the quote isn't searchable.

Comment: Possible duplication of [Tell MySQL to start using utf8 encoding without 'convert to'-ing it](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33365/tell-mysql-to-start-using-utf-8-encoding-without-convert-toing-it) ?

Comment: Bull's eye @JoelHinz. I think I need an eye specialist than stackoverflow.com. Please let me know what should I do of this question. You can answer it and I'll accept it because you did put an effort to read it.

Comment: Side note: You should really use [get_page_by_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan It doesn't works for special characters. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190629/get-page-by-title-not-working-if-special-characters-are-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `’` character isn't the same as `'` - looks like you have one in the title and another in the query. Either character is separately searchable, but they seem to have gotten mixed up by accident.